# Compile and use System C under Windows 10 Ubuntu bash

Tags: bash, windows-10, systemc

I've been trying to compile a simple System C executable under windows 10 bash without success, after some search, I've found this link: 
http://topazus-dev.blogspot.com/2016/06/systemc-on-windows-using-bash-on-windows.html
Explaining that dynamic linking does not work correctly under Windows 10 bash, so a workaround is to use static linking, I've tried compiling the following example program:

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <iostream>

int sc_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hi\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program itself is not important, the point is to be able to compile it, the commands I used were:

```
g++ -Wall -g -I/mnt/c/home/systemc-2.3.2/include -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ main.o -L /mnt/c/home/systemc-2.3.2/lib-linux64 -Wl, -Bstatic -lsystemc -Wl, -Bdynamic -pthread -o main
```

But the process fails and the following error appears:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory /usr/bin/ld:
>   cannot find : No such file or directory collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

I've compiled programs with other libraries besides System C, they work as expected, I've also tried to compile directly with the .a version of System C present on the same folder as the .so, that caused a lot undefined references in the linking process, so it doesn't work that way either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try and move the linker flag `-lsystemc` to the end of the command?

Comment: Where is your GCC path? You might need to add the path to your default PATH environment variable so that GCC can invoke ld binary. If your system doesn't have BFD ld, you might need to specify `-fuse-ld=gold` to use gold linker instead of ld.